# Correct spelling: Magic or Magick?

Tags: orthography

Is it *Magic*; or is it *Magick*?

I think the latter is the correct way, even though the latter version is listed in [some dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/magick). Why is that?

Comment: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is a product name.

Comment: There is a series of books that spells it Magick to distinguish between the occult and simple stage magic. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magick_%28Aleister_Crowley%29) it's the author prerogative to use any spelling he chooses.

Comment: The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=magick) has an entry for _magick_ that explains the variant rather well. In future questions, you'll want to do some of your own research, and incorporate your findings into the question. The Stack Exchange isn't designed to be the first place to go to ask a question – not until you've done some pretty thorough investigating yourself, and you find yourself still stumped. Even then, generally speaking, when you tell us what you've researched and why you're still stumped, your question is likely to be appreciated even more.

Comment: meta: Some knowledgeable people here evidently differ in their opinions. Is this GR? If so, is *Magick* an orthographic monster? If not, is DougM's answer the one (also, Heisenberg, Jim)? What about the down votes then? (Will they be retracted?)

Answer (score 5):

**Magic**, as in a general supernatural or supernatural-seeming force such as that occasionally claimed by illusionists and is popular in fantasy literature, is spelled without the K.

**Magick**, with a K, is an intentional variant that specifically refers to ritual prayers as practiced by various neo-pagan religions.  While some of these persons sincerely believe their prayers are equivalent to the supernatural abilities of fairy-tale witches, the spelling is an intentional deviation to separate the practice from slight-of-hand and illusion.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the word 'Magick' was first associated with the medieval occultist, Heinreich Cornelius Agrippa. However, it was popularized in the 20th century by the infamous British occultist, Aleister Crowlely, who defined it as "the Science and Art of causing Change to occur in conformity with Will".

Comment: [Heinreich Cornelius Agrippa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Cornelius_Agrippa) did not speak or write in anything close to modern English with its normalized spelling, FWIW.

Comment: Of course he didn't speak or write modernized English (he was a 15th Century figure), but he did use the word Magick in his 'De Occulta Philosophia' tetralogy. However, it wasn't until the 20th century that Crowley institutionalized the word with his esoteric cult, Thelema.

Comment: The question is about spelling; I'm sure we can find plenty of instances of the variant spellings "magic", "magik", "magick", and so forth if we examine foreign languages and pre-standard English.

Comment: You may be correct, but I cannot comment on that as I haven't examined the etymology of the word outside the esoteric world.

Comment: @Heisenberg, the spelling "magick" appears in the [1651 English translation](http://esotericarchives.com/agrippa/agrippa1.htm) of "De Occulta Philosophia" by "J.F.". In the [latin original](http://www.e-rara.ch/doi/10.3931/e-rara-278) the corresponding word is "magia".